# CKEditor 4.x replaceClass doesn't work

Tags: cakephp-2.0, ckeditor4.x

I have a couple op CKEditor 4.x questions and here's the most important one. I'm trying to implement CKEditor in my own CakePHP cms system via the [replaceClass](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-cfg-replaceClass) functionality, but it seems that doesn't work for me.

That's how my HTML textarea looks like:

```
<div class="form-group required">
    <label for="PostContent">Content</label>
    <textarea name="data[Post][content]" class="ckeditor" rows="10" cols="30" id="PostContent" required="required"></textarea>
</div>
```

The javascript files with custom configuration:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/coaster_cms/js/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/coaster_cms/js/ckeditor/config_custom.js"></script>
```

The custom CKEditor configuration (config_custom.js):

```
CKEDITOR.replaceClass('ckeditor', {
    language: 'nl',
    height: '400px',
    // speciale karakters niet escapen
    resize_enabled: false,
    entities_latin: false,
    entities_greek: false,
    entities: false,
    basicEntities: false
});
```

The strangest thing is that it does work when I use "CKEDITOR.replace" on id level like this:

```
CKEDITOR.replace('PostContent', {
    language: 'nl',
    height: '400px',
    // speciale karakters niet escapen
    resize_enabled: false,
    entities_latin: false,
    entities_greek: false,
    entities: false,
    basicEntities: false
});
```

Thanks in advance for analysing the code and supporting me ;)

Answer (score 1):

according to the docs, replaceclass only accepts a string and ckeditor is the default.

http://docs.ckeditor.com/source/themedui.html#CKEDITOR-cfg-replaceClass

Comment: But there's no way to add some custom properties (language, height, ...) to those editors? Or do you have to declare them both (replaceClass AND replace)?

Comment: According to the docs, those parameters can be passed via config. You can use an object, or individual variables like below.

[link]http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_size[/link]

`CKEDITOR.config.height = 500;` (passing no unit forces pixels)

[link]http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-language[/link]

`CKEDITOR.config.language = 'nl';`

Comment: Thanks for the support imvain2! I just discovered there's a better way to set config on classed textarea's: via jquery Adapter: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_jquery. Now I can do this: $('textarea.ckeditor').ckeditor({});